# NHibernate ICritery add IEnumerable<int>?

Tags: .net, nhibernate

I'm fairly new to NHibernate and I'm trying to modify a criteria that currently takes a single integer, using something like (simplified):

```
int attributeId = 5;
Attribute attributeAlias = null;

var criteria = DetachedCriteria<Asset>.Create(() => attributeAlias)
.Add(() => attributeAlias.Id == attributeId )
```

But I want to change it to allow passing in a list of attributeIds, similar to this.

```
IEnumerable<int> attributeIds = new List<int> ( ) { 5, 6, 7, 8 };
```

I have not yet been able to figure out how to update the criteria to allow a list. Does anyone have any references on doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int[] attributeIds = { 5, 6, 7, 8 };

ICriteria criteria = Session.CreateCriteria();
criteria.Add(Expression.In("Id", attributeIds)); //this is the important part
criteria.List();
```

**Update:** From what Zenox also contributed:

```
ICriteria criteria = Session.CreateCriteria();
criteria.Add(Restrictions.In ( LambdaProjection.Property ( ( ) => attributeAlias.Id ), attributeIds .ToArray ( ) ));
criteria.List();
```

Comment: Thanks, I also just found the: 'Restrictions.In ( LambdaProjection.Property ( ( ) => attributeAlias.Id ), attributeIds .ToArray ( ) )' which also works.